# how to generate thumbnail for all video file using ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg, getfiles

I successfully generated a thumbnail for a video file using ffmpeg and now I want to create a thumbnail for each video in directory. How can I read all video files in the directory and generate thumbnail for each video using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

**DirectoryIntoThumbNails(@"C:\VideoFolder", "*.mpg")**

```
void DirectoryIntoThumbNails(string sDir, string extension) 
{
    try 
    {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
       {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, extension)) 
        {
           SystemDiagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Ffmpeg.exe " + f + commandYouUsedSuccessfullyOnOneFile)
        }
        //Uncomment this if you want it to be recursive - all sub folders
        //DirSearch(d, extension);
       }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.IO;

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

Browse this link for [Get Files from Directory](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/)

Now manipulate the array `filePaths` and generate thumbnail for the videos . .